# JavaScript querySelector and CSS :target pseudo-class

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, pseudo-class, selectors-api, domcontentloaded

I am trying to get the targeted element with the pseudo-class `:target` after document load.
I created the following example to illustrate the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
                console.log(document.querySelector(":target"));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I load `test.html`, then the console outputs :

```
null
```

If I load `test.html#test` on Chrome and Opera, then the console outputs :

```
null
```

If I load `test.html#test` on Firefox and IE11, then the console outputs :

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

My questions are :

1. Which browsers have the correct behaviour ?
2. Does `DOMContentLoaded` is the correct event to call `querySelector(":target")` ?
3. Is there another way to get targeted element after document load ?

PS : I succeeded to fix the problem on Chrome and Opera thanks to `setTimeout` but It is not a good solution. Does someone has a better idea ?

EDIT : I found a similar issue with JQuery [Selecting :target on document.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371439/selecting-target-on-document-ready)

Comment: From the [Selectors API Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar): _"Authors are advised that while the use of **pseudo-elements in selectors is permitted, they will not match any elements in the document, and thus would not result in any elements being returned**. Therefore, authors are advised to avoid the use of pseudo-elements in selectors that are passed to the methods defined in this specification. "_

Comment: But `:target` is a [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) not a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

Comment: In `onload` it works [fine for me](https://test-target-selector.glitch.me/#target) in Chrome, but not in Safari... An hack around would be to have a small transition (0.01s) set on `:target` and listen for the transitionend event.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like **Firefox** has the ideal behaviour, though maybe not the correct one.

Nevertheless, as an alternative, you can use:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => document.querySelector(window.location.hash));
```

and that will work in all browsers.

Comment: _"It looks like Firefox has the ideal behaviour..."_ - How is the violation of the specification an _"ideal behaviour"_?

Comment: @Andreas - Specs are neither infallible nor immutable.

Comment: If I load the document with an empty location.hash, I get an error `Uncaught DOMException`. That means that I need to add a check before `querySelector`, nevertheless it is a good alternative to `:target`.

Comment: Re: _"That means that I need to add a check before `querySelector`"_. Right. You can straightforwardly write something like: `if (window.location.hash !== '') { console.log(document.querySelector(window.location.hash)); } else { console.log('The current URL contains no hashfragment.'); }`.

Comment: This *will* not catch https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment (already there in Chrome) since the [`:target`](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment#target) matches the parent-element of the text-fragment, but `location.hash` is not set.

Comment: @Andreas: Note that Baptistou has now corrected you above. Firefox is not the one in violation here. The old [selectors-api tests](https://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/selectors-api-testsuite/level1-additional-report.html) show that Chrome and Safari are in violation. web-platform-tests contains a workaround that uses requestAnimationFrame().

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/selectors-api-testsuite/level1-additional-report.html) with WebKit- and Blink-based browsers that has never been directly addressed. The workaround suggested by web-platform-tests is to [request an animation frame](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/dom/nodes/ParentNode-querySelector-All-xht.xht#L15), which only happens after page rendering, at which point the `:target` pseudo seems to match successfully:

```js
async_test(function() {
  var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
  var self = this;
  frame.onload = function() {
    // :target doesn't work before a page rendering on some browsers.  We run
    // tests after an animation frame because it may be later than the first
    // page rendering.
    requestAnimationFrame(self.step_func_done(init.bind(self, frame)));
  };
  frame.src = "ParentNode-querySelector-All-content.xht#target";
  document.body.appendChild(frame);
})
```

My testing shows that simply using `onload` works fine, but the author may be on to something and besides, a single call to `requestAnimationFrame()` costs practically nothing, so you may as well follow suit.

The following test uses `onload` (as opposed to `DOMContentLoaded`, which fires immediately after the DOM tree has been constructed but not necessarily rendered):

```
data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><script>window.onload=function(){console.log(document.querySelector(":target"));};</script><div id="test"></div>#test
```

The following test uses `requestAnimationFrame()` in conjunction with `onload`:

```
data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><script>window.onload=requestAnimationFrame(function(){console.log(document.querySelector(":target"));});</script><div id="test"></div>#test
```

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph, it seems to be necessary to call requestAnimationFrame in `onload`,  at least for Chrome, and certainly because of https://crbug.com/1018120